# Is there a way to determine rough distance between Apple Watch and iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I know this might be unanswerable until the Apple Watch is released.

But does anyone know if there may be a way to determine the rough distance (in feet) between an Apple Watch and an iPhone?

Comment: Can you explain why? It might help.

Comment: If the Apple Watch appears as a bluetooth device, in theory you could [use the RSSI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13466412/2446155) of the Apple Watch using Core Bluetooth to get the signal strength. But, there are [many factors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3625388/2446155) other than _distance_ that could affect that reading.

Comment: Lol. Yeah. Put them right next to each other and watch the signal drop in half when you put your hand in the way. Not really any way to do it.

Comment: You can only check reacablility of any of the device (iPhone or watch)  using watchConnectivity.  Check this link for Core Bluetooth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872366/objective-c-ios-6-ble-bluetooth-4-0-distance-calculation?lq=1 , it give information like RSSI(Received Signal Strength Indicator)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the [WatchKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WatchKit_framework/index.html#classes) does not give you this kind of information, since third-party apps are still quite limited in what they can do. For example, they [require a connection to the iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/).

There is some speculation that later this year, third-party developers will be given more access to the hardware, e.g., bluetooth, accelerometer, pulse, NFC, etc.